# How to get user Info using graph API like facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

How to get the below user's information using graph API : 
 1. user/like 
 2. user/interests
 in IOS Facebook sdk 4.0 for IOS 9.

Please help me if anyone have any idea here.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: see this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

Comment: Ok Thank you so much. :)